# Cross platform SDK

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sdk, cross-platform

I am new to React Native. So here goes my scenario:

We need to create a new SDK that would be embedded into multiple technologies: React Web (JS), React Native APPs, iOS Apps (Swift and Obj-c), and Android Apps (Kotlin and Java). This SDK will offer:

- APIs to get access tokens (issued by our corporate authenticator) so that the APP can talk to our API Gateway; something on the lines of getCurrentAccessToken();
- Standard screens for login, Change Password, Forgot Password, OTP, etc; The UI should look and feel NATIVE to each target platform that it will be running on (Web, iOS, Android). Transitioning from a Native Screen to SDK's Screen should be smooth.
- Be small (package size) and have OK/Hermes performance on both API Calls and Screen loading times (it doesn't need to be as fast as Native, as this SDK will be used once or twice every time the user starts the main APP);

I have checked boden.io (C++) but it would not work on WEB. It might still be an option (having 2 SDKs, one for WEB one for Mobile) so I didn't rule it out yet.

Is such a thing feasible in React Native? If feasible, is it a good idea?

PS: I know I would still need native binds/wrappers for each technology so that the SDK looks NATIVE to the caller, but that would be a minor issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use go lang and gomobile to build the sdk for iOS, Android and Web.